# SOAPUI Groovy script inserting xml node with custom value

Tags: java, xml, groovy, soapui

So I've got a step that takes some numerical ids & looks up their values in a database. I want to be able to edit the response xml & include the values gotten from the database for readability purposes.

I figured out how to add the xml node into the xmlHolder, however I can't seem to put a value inside the node.

This is the closest 'seemingly' working code:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def dbResult = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["getNames"].getResponseContent()
def xmlOfferNames = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(dbResult)

def names = xmlOfferNames.getNodeValues("//NAME")
def codes = xmlOfferNames.getNodeValues("//ID")

def recs = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Item#Reply")

def insert
for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){
    for(node in recs.getDomNodes("//Item[ID='"+codes[i]+"']")){
        //insert = '<NAME>'+names[i]+'</NAME>' //nothing is taking strings
        //node.appendNode(new Node(node, 'NAME', names[i])) //dne constructor
        insert = node.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(node.getNamespaceURI(), "NAME")
        //log.info names[i]
        insert.setNodeValue(names[i])
        //log.info insert.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
        node.insertBefore(insert , node.getFirstChild())
    }
}

recs.updateProperty()
log.info recs.getXml()
```

However, when it prints out the generated xml I just have empty `<NAME/>` tags, with no value.

I've tried to use `insert.setTextContent()` but it says `java.long.RuntimeException: DOM Level 3 Not implemented`. I don't see anything else I could use to set the value.

(semi-relatedly, it oddly doesn't update the xml in my step either, but I haven't started researching that yet)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out you can't just add a string to the element, you have to make a text node.

```
insert.appendChild(node.getOwnerDocument().createTextNode(names[i]))
```

Comment: Code only answers with no explanation are considered low quality, please add an explanation as to how the line above is to be used and how it solves the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `holder` to modify your `XML` try using `XmlSlurper`:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xml = '''<sample>
    <RetailRecommendation>
        <OfferCode>a1</OfferCode>
    </RetailRecommendation>
    <RetailRecommendation>
        <OfferCode>b2</OfferCode>
    </RetailRecommendation>
    <RetailRecommendation>
        <OfferCode>a1</OfferCode>
        <OfferCode>ac3</OfferCode>
    </RetailRecommendation>
</sample>
'''

def recs = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def names = ['kilo','mega','giga']
def codes = ['a1','b2','ac3']

// for each name
names.eachWithIndex{ name, i ->

     // find all OfferCode elements inside RetailRecommendation
     // where value is in codes[i] array
    recs.RetailRecommendation.'**'.findAll { node ->
        node.name() == 'OfferCode' && node.text() == codes[i] 
    }.each{ elem ->  // for each element...
        // create the new node to add
        def nodeToAdd = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<OFFER_NAME>' + name + '</OFFER_NAME>')
        // and append the node to your element
        elem.parent().appendNode(nodeToAdd)
    }
}

log.info XmlUtil.serialize(recs)
```

This results in:

```
<sample>
   <RetailRecommendation>
      <OfferCode>a1</OfferCode>
      <OFFER_NAME>kilo</OFFER_NAME>
   </RetailRecommendation>
   <RetailRecommendation>
      <OfferCode>b2</OfferCode>
      <OFFER_NAME>mega</OFFER_NAME>
   </RetailRecommendation>
   <RetailRecommendation>
      <OfferCode>a1</OfferCode>
      <OfferCode>ac3</OfferCode>
      <OFFER_NAME>kilo</OFFER_NAME>
      <OFFER_NAME>giga</OFFER_NAME>
   </RetailRecommendation>
</sample>
```

Inside your code you can keep using `holder` to get the `names` and `codes` but change the way you modify the response, all together could be something like:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def dbResult = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["getOfferNames"].getResponseContent()
def xmlOfferNames = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(dbResult)

def names = xmlOfferNames.getNodeValues("//NAME")
def codes = xmlOfferNames.getNodeValues("//OFFERCODE1")

def recs = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.expand('${getRetailRecommendation#Response}'))

// for each name
names.eachWithIndex{ name, i ->

     // find all OfferCode elements inside RetailRecommendation
     // where value is in codes[i] array
    recs.RetailRecommendation.'**'.findAll { node ->
        node.name() == 'OfferCode' && node.text() == codes[i] 
    }.each{ elem ->
        // for each node found it
        def nodeToAdd = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<OFFER_NAME>' + name + '</OFFER_NAME>')
        elem.parent().appendNode(nodeToAdd)
    }
}

log.info XmlUtil.serialize(recs)
```

Hope this helps,